# Getting access denied error when attempting to call Microsoft Graph API

Tags: typescript, express, microsoft-graph-api

I've got an app registered in Azure directory as a single tenant app and according to Integration Assistant there are no errors/warnings.  However, when I try to use the Graph Api client to send mail I run into one of two issues depending on the way I am calling it.

App.ts

```
import AppAuthProvider from './AppAuthProvider';
import { Client } from '@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client';
import cookieParser from 'cookie-parser';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import express from 'express';
import logger from 'morgan';
import path from 'path';
import routes from './routes';

dotenv.config();

const app = express();

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);

const client = Client.initWithMiddleware({
  authProvider: new AppAuthProvider(),
});

const mail = {
  subject: 'Microsoft Graph Test',
  toRecipients: [
    {
      emailAddress: {
        name: 'To User',
        address: 'you@someone.com',
      },
    },
  ],
  from: {
    emailAddress: {
      name: 'From User',
      address: 'you@someone.com',
    },
  },
  body: {
    content:
      '<h1>Microsoft Graph Test</h1>',
    contentType: 'html',
  },
};

try {
  console.log('here');
  client.api('/me/sendmail').post({ message: mail });
} catch (error) {
  console.log(`-----------------Error: ${error}-----------------`);
}

export default app;
```

According to [Microsoft Graph Authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=Javascript#ClientCredentialsProvider) page a custom authentication provider is required for client credential apps. This works and is returning the accessToken

AppAuthProvider.ts

```
import 'isomorphic-fetch';

import * as msal from '@azure/msal-node';

import { AuthenticationProvider } from '@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client';
import { Configuration } from '@azure/msal-node';

export default class AppAuthProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {
  private msalConfig: Configuration = {
    auth: {
      clientId: process.env.OAUTH_APP_ID!,
      authority: `${process.env.OAUTH_AUTHORITY}${process.env.OAUTH_TENANT_ID}`,
      clientSecret: process.env.OAUTH_APP_SECRET,
    },
    system: {
      loggerOptions: {
        loggerCallback(loglevel, message, containsPii) {
          console.log(message);
        },
        piiLoggingEnabled: false,
        logLevel: msal.LogLevel.Verbose,
      },
    },
  };

  /**
   *
   */
  public async getAccessToken(): Promise<string> {
    // create msal application object
    const cca = new msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(this.msalConfig);

    try {
      const result = await cca.acquireTokenByClientCredential({
        scopes: [process.env.OAUTH_GRAPH_URI!],
      });

      if (result === null) {
        return '';
      }

      return result.accessToken;
    } catch (error) {
      return error;
    }
  }
}
```

First, if I call the api using `client.api("/me/sendmail")` I am met with an access denied error. Although the app is registered in Azure as an "Application" with permissions for Mail.Send to send mail as any user.

```
node:21715) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Access is denied. Check credentials and try again.
    at new GraphError (/Users/jason/Projects/outlook-api-tutorial/node_modules/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client/src/GraphError.ts:59:3)
    at Function.GraphErrorHandler.constructErrorFromResponse (/Users/jason/Projects/outlook-api-tutorial/node_modules/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client/src/GraphErrorHandler.ts:62:18)
    at Function.<anonymous> (/Users/jason/Projects/outlook-api-tutorial/node_modules/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client/src/GraphErrorHandler.ts:89:31)
    at step (/Users/jason/Projects/outlook-api-tutorial/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:141:27)
    at Object.next (/Users/jason/Projects/outlook-api-tutorial/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:122:57)
    at /Users/jason/Projects/outlook-api-tutorial/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:115:75
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Object.__awaiter (/Users/jason/Projects/outlook-api-tutorial/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:111:16)
    at Function.GraphErrorHandler.getError (/Users/jason/Projects/outlook-api-tutorial/node_modules/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client/lib/src/GraphErrorHandler.js:88:24)
    at GraphRequest.<anonymous> (/Users/jason/Projects/outlook-api-tutorial/node_modules/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client/src/GraphRequest.ts:386:55)
```

The second method I attempted was to change the `client.api` call to `client.api("/users/{userId}")` using the no-reply email account I created specifically for this scenario.  When doing this, I get the following error:

```
(node:21922) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Specified HTTP method is not allowed for the request target.
    at new GraphError (/Users/jason/Projects/outlook-api-tutorial/node_modules/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client/src/GraphError.ts:59:3)
    at Function.GraphErrorHandler.constructErrorFromResponse (/Users/jason/Projects/outlook-api-tutorial/node_modules/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client/src/GraphErrorHandler.ts:62:18)
    at Function.<anonymous> (/Users/jason/Projects/outlook-api-tutorial/node_modules/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client/src/GraphErrorHandler.ts:89:31)
    at step (/Users/jason/Projects/outlook-api-tutorial/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:141:27)
    at Object.next (/Users/jason/Projects/outlook-api-tutorial/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:122:57)
    at /Users/jason/Projects/outlook-api-tutorial/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:115:75
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Object.__awaiter (/Users/jason/Projects/outlook-api-tutorial/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:111:16)
    at Function.GraphErrorHandler.getError (/Users/jason/Projects/outlook-api-tutorial/node_modules/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client/lib/src/GraphErrorHandler.js:88:24)
    at GraphRequest.<anonymous> (/Users/jason/Projects/outlook-api-tutorial/node_modules/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client/src/GraphRequest.ts:386:55)
```

This is data returned in AuthProvider

```
{
  "authority": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/*** REMOVED ***/",
  "uniqueId": "",
  "tenantId": "",
  "scopes": [
    "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default",
    "openid",
    "profile",
    "offline_access"
  ],
  "account": null,
  "idToken": "",
  "idTokenClaims": {},
  "accessToken": "*** REMOVED ***",
  "fromCache": false,
  "expiresOn": "2021-01-17T09:13:56.000Z",
  "extExpiresOn": "2021-01-17T10:13:55.000Z",
  "familyId": "",
  "tokenType": "Bearer",
  "state": "",
  "cloudGraphHostName": "",
  "msGraphHost": ""
}
```

Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was a combination of a few things.  First, I needed to await on the client response so I modified the call from

```
try {
  console.log('here');
  client.api('/me/sendmail').post({ message: mail });
} catch (error) {
  console.log(`-----------------Error: ${error}-----------------`);
}
```

to

```
async function sendMail() {
  try {
    const response = await client
      .api('/users/you@someone.com/sendMail')
      .post({ message: mail }, (error: GraphError, response: any) => {
        if (error) {
          console.log(`Graph Error: ${error}`);
          return;
        }
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
      });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(`-----------------Error: ${error}-----------------`);
  }
}
```

The second problem is that each time I changed the api call from `/me/sendmail` to `/users/userId` I left off the route sendmail.  That is why I kept getting the HTTP error.  However, I couldn't get it working with the user id either but the principal name (i.e. email address) worked like a charm!